# How difficult is it to emigrate from Earth in The Expanse?

Tags: the-expanse-2015, the-expanse-novels

In The Expanse we learn that the majority of people living on Earth have very little opportunity and survive with a basic income in squalor.

How difficult would it be for one of these 'average' people to emigrate from Earth to either Mars or the Belt?

Comment: It is worth noting that during the early colonization of those parts of the America controlled by the British is was not unusual for poor people to accept a period of indentured servitude to pay for their passage (i.e. they couldn't muster the resources to pay for the travel). Later (once steamships were a thing) steerage passage was within the reach of the poor who had *some* resources if they were willing to arrive broke, but that was accomplished by packing them in like cargo. Discuss.

Comment: The issue of getting off Earth is discussed in the short story The Churn, which shows how Amos got off planet. It addresses your question exactly. Enjoy!

Comment: @JamesfromNZ Good to know thanks! I'll have a look into it.

Comment: I am not sure whatever belt would be preferable. Show suggests that they would have also a very little opportunity but without a basic income. Mars attitude was not clear but given their behavior toward Belters it is dubious whatever they would be more happy about other poor people.